# What are the available AWS services for react native?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We are using Amazon s3 for video storage in one of React native applications. We want to use AWS Elemental MediaConvert for file-based video processing, and Amazon CloudFront for delivery. Are these services available for React native ? 
I could not see these services available in the below library.
[https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-react-native]

If AWS Elemental MediaConvert and Amazon CloudFront are not available for React native yet then what other options to go for video processing and delivery ?

Answer (score 1):

In ReactNative you can use all the AWS services with this SDK package [AWS JavaScript SDK with React Native Support](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-react-native). It includes support for all AWS services including, AWS MediaConvert, AWS Cloudfront, and AWS MediaLive.

On the GitHub page that you provided, aws-sdk-react-native, it states

> This developer preview is currently under review and we will be
>   looking to merge the contents in the future under a single repository
>   for all AWS React Native functionality. In the meantime, we recommend
>   you leverage the AWS Amplify library or the AWS JavaScript SDK with
>   React Native support.

Here is a sample what using the SDK looks like in a ReactNative app.

```
// import entire SDK
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

//Sample call to AWS MediaConvert
var mediaconvert = new AWS.MediaConvert();
mediaconvert.cancelJob(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```